# What to study in interstellar space?

Tags: spacecraft, interstellar-travel

Are there advantages to observing the universe from interstellar space? What kind of scientific experiments would be useful for a spacecraft outside of the Solar System's Oort cloud?

Comment: How about interstellar space itself? Until we get there we're just making observations, when we get their we're making measurements.

Comment: I think in a way that is also part of my question. What measurements can we make in interstellar space?

Comment: One way to narrow this down would be to ask what a specific probe could measure. The only probe currently out there is Voyager 1, but Voyager 2 will be there soon. Pioneer 10 and 11 are out that way, but we've lost contact with them. New Horizons will eventually get there, but it is not equipped to do measurements in interstellar space. I don't know of any proposal for a future interstellar probe that has been approved.